# Jquery On Blur sometimes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search that on focus grows bigger and on blur grows smaller. My problem is even when you click in the suggest area it causes the animating to run. Is there a way to make it so that if your click in the suggest area this code does not execute.

```
$('.search').blur(function(e) {
    if ( !clickedInSuggest ) {
        $(this).animate({ width : '50px' }, 150);
    }
});
```

html:

```
<li class="search">
    <form class="searchContainer" action="<?php echo Uri::create('search') ?>" method="get">
        <input autocomplete="off" name="name" placeholder="Search" tabindex="1" type="text" value="" />
        <button type="submit" class="submit"></button>
    </form>
    <div class="suggestions">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

Comment: can you post the HTML that goes with this?

Comment: What is the suggest area? Please post the related HTML markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...Wait...I just solved this problem in a different situation and now I remember:

```
$(function(){

   var flag=true;

   $('.suggestions').mousedown(function(){
       flag=false;
   })
   $('.suggestions').mouseup(function(){
      flag=true;
   })

   $('.search').blur(function(e){
       if(flag==false){
           e.preventDefault();
       }
      $('....').animate({...})..etc

   })
})
```

Why this works is because the mousedown event fires before the blur event, and the blur event fires before the click event.

Good luck.